# Cannot power on a VM vSphere "The operation is not allowed in the current state"

Tags: virtual-machines, vmware-vcenter

I have a server that looks like this

> Server1
>
> Server2
>
> *Server3 (inaccessible)*
>
> Server4

When I try to power it on, it says "The operation is not allowed in the current state." I have checked the host and the VM itself and haven't seen any pending or failed tasks. What else can I check?

EDIT:

I was able to browse to the VM files in the datastore.

Comment: Check if the storage used for the VM files are accessible.

Comment: Can you browse to the VM's files?

Comment: What happened right before this? :)

Comment: I don't know. Nothing, as far as I know. Is there a log file to check? One on the host?

Comment: Have you tried powering it down?  Probably not the case with it being  inaccessible, but may as well be thorough, and try - I've seen VMs get in a state where they're powered off, but vSphere thinks they're still powered on, and issuing a power down command usually to syncs up the power status, allowing you to power it on again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to get it to boot. Here are the steps I followed:

1. Locate the .vmx file (remember which data store)
2. Remove the vm for inventory
3. Browse to the datastore and re-add the VM (right click the .vmx
   file)

Comment: that's why I asked you to browse to it, vC DB VM entry corrupted

Comment: it's dumb, but this worked on esxi 6.7

Comment: Nope, right clicking has "remove from inventory" greyed out, does not work.

Comment: Something may have changed in the 9 years that this answer was first posted.

Answer (score 4):

Verify that the server is not in maintenance mode.
It is required for shutdown/restart that the server first be put in maintenance mode and VM's will not start up in this state.

Comment: Bingo!!!  ESXi was in maintenance mode.  I pulled it out of maintenance mode and the guest OS's Power On button became enabled and clicking on it started the VM with no issues.

Comment: You would think VMware would put a warning line that the system is in Maintenance Mode just like it does when SSH is enabled.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to power on the VM from command line with this command:

```
vim-cmd vmsvc/power.on xxx
```

The vimid `xxx` can be found using

```
vim-cmd vmsvc/getallvms | grep -i "vm name"
```

Comment: Apparently the output from vim-cmd vmsvc/getallvms is a little different now, so grepping for "vm name" didn't work.  Just remove the pipe and grep and you can see the vmid (it's presented as a table with Vmid as the column heading).  Anyway, powering on the VM did not work.  I get "Power on failed."  Not very nice that it doesn't state WHY it failed.

Comment: This saved me, thank you. The above used to work (when remove from inventory), but not anymore, ESXi 6.7

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work every time, but saved me on more than one occasion:

Log in using SSH or the console, then issue the following command:

```
services.sh restart
```

This doesn't touch any running VMs, but may release any locks that are preventing you from touching one specific VM.

Answer (score 0):

Reboot the host and see if you have the server linked into a cluster or maybe you use shared storage - scheduled tasks , anything that might be related . There must be something happening on the host that maybe is not directly visible from the basic command screen . Another way of finding out would be to go on the server console and see what is eating up the most resources - that is most likelly blocking the state.

Comment: I would have tried this, but I have other VMs on there that I wasn't able to vmotion off.

Comment: http://jlscz.blogspot.ro/2011/04/pre.html you can see how to access the vmotion logs

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was because the VMs were in a state of removing snapshots.

Answer (score 0):

You can't manipulate an *inaccessible* VM. Usually, the ESXi host has lost access to the *.vmx* file, even if temporarily (usually indicating storage problems). Once the host has given up, the VM remains inaccessible even if it's still running.

If you are sure that the *.vmx* is accessible (check via SSH, browse storage, ...) then you can make the host re-establish access to the .vmx, without changing the VM's state:

via **PowerCLI**:

```
#Get Inaccessible Virtual Machines
$VMs = Get-View -ViewType VirtualMachine | ?{$_.Runtime.ConnectionState -eq "invalid" -or $_.Runtime.ConnectionState -eq "inaccessible"} | select name,@{Name="GuestConnectionState";E={$_.Runtime.ConnectionState}}
 
write-host "---------------------------"
Write-host "Inaccessible VMs"
write-host "---------------------------"
 
$VMs
 
#Reload VMs into inventory
Get-View -ViewType VirtualMachine | ?{$VMs} | %{$_.reload()}
 
#Show new state of reloaded VMs
$ReloadedVMs = Get-View -ViewType VirtualMachine | ?{$VMs} | select name,@{Name="GuestConnectionState";E={$_.Runtime.ConnectionState}}
 
write-host "---------------------------"
write-host "Reloaded VMs"
write-host "---------------------------"
 
$ReloadedVMs
```

via **SSH console**:

```
for a in $(vim-cmd vmsvc/getallvms 2>&1 |grep invalid |awk '{print $4}'|cut -d \' -f2);do vim-cmd vmsvc/reload $a;done
```

or simply

```
vim-cmd vmsvc/reload <vmname>
```

for a **single VM**.